# corner radius on layer and shadows

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, layer, shadow, cornerradius

I have a map view inside a cell and I want it to have corner radius and shadow. I either get only rounded corners OR only the shadow and no rounder corners when i set masks to bounds ON/OFF respectively. I looked up to this example:
[Can't add a corner radius and a shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316424/cant-add-a-corner-radius-and-a-shadow)

but with no success.
What am I missing? thank you in advance!

```
[[cell.map1 layer] setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[[cell.map1 layer] setShadowOpacity:0.8f];
[[cell.map1 layer] setShadowRadius:20.0f];
[[cell.map1 layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 3)];
       // [[cell.map1 layer] setMasksToBounds:NO];
[[cell.map1 layer] setShouldRasterize:YES];
[[cell.map1 layer] setCornerRadius:20];
```

Comment: why have you commented [[cell.map1 layer] setMasksToBounds:NO];?

Comment: I was just testing the possible solutions. It doesn't work when I set it to YES or NO. It either shows only the shadow or only makes the corners rounded

Answer (score 0):

Setting mask to bounds is like setting clip to bounds. This means nothing can be outside the bounds and the shadow lays outside of the bounds.
[Check out this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690972/why-maskstobounds-yes-prevents-calayer-shadow)